# Is it possible to center text vertically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is it possilble as of `1.0.0-alpha03` to align text center vertically without nesting components `Stack -> Text`

```kotlin
 Text(
       modifier = Modifier
                 .size(150.dp, 30.dp)
                 .background(Colors.ChipGray, RoundedCornerShape(50)),
       textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
       text = start.value.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd. MM. HH:mm")),
      )
```

Comment: Do to want to align the text vertically inside the `Text()` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In General, it is possible but I would not suggest it.

You could use offset to shift the text relative to the background by half of the font size, but I am not sure if you can access the height of the used font here.

```kotlin
        Text(
            text = start.value.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd. MM. HH:mm")),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(150.dp, 30.dp)
                .background(Color.Gray, RoundedCornerShape(50))
                .offset(y = fontHeightHalf)
        )
```

Use the stack instead, like:

```kotlin
        Stack (
            alignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(150.dp, 30.dp)
                .background(Color.Gray, RoundedCornerShape(50)),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = start.value.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd. MM. HH:mm")),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
        }
```

Edit: Updated version to 1.0.0-alpha03

Comment: Thank you so much for a clarification. With a Stack there is even better way as of 1.0.0-alpha03. You can set align parameter directly on the Stack. https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1398696

BTW: the gravity modifer was replaced by align

Comment: That is nice, makes it a little bit clearer. I updated the answer to the newer version, I was still running 1.0.0-alpha01.